# parsing XML from XML string for actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to parse out the nodeName but nothing was return, what is wrong with my script?

```
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
import flash.xml.XMLNode;
import flash.xml.XMLNodeType;

var MaintainXML:XML = 
<letter><to>senocular</to><body>Get a life</body></letter>;

trace("status"+MaintainXML.status); // traces "0" (No error)
trace("nodeName" + MaintainXML.firstChild.nodeName); // traces "letter"
trace("nodeName" + MaintainXML.firstChild.firstChild.nodeName); // traces "to"
trace("nodeValue"+MaintainXML.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue); // traces
```

Comment: how to accept the answer. I did click the up arrow. Is there somewhere else? lol don't where to accept. I see now. The check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use methods or properties on your XML that are not existent: Neither `status`, nor `firstChild`, nor `nodeName` are available for the [XML Object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html).  Flash will interpret those calls as a search query, so it looks for child nodes with the name "status", resp. "firstChild" as in

```
<root>
   <status />
    <firstChild />
</root>
```

and returns an empty XMLList, because of course it cannot find such nodes.

Also, your MaintainXMLs root node is `<letter>`, so the first child would be `<to>`.

Try this:

```
var MaintainXML : XML = <letter><to>senocular</to><body>Get a life</body></letter>;

trace( "nodeName:" + MaintainXML.to.name() ); // traces "to"
trace( "nodeValue:" + MaintainXML.to.toString() ); // traces "senocular"
```